# Help with a proof about Generalised Beauville Groups.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to understand a proof from a research paper and there are certain aspects that allude me.  First some background.

[image: Beauville Group]

More importantly, a generalised Beauville groups is defined as having d(G)>2,

[image: Generalised Beauville Group]

I am currently trying to follow the thread of this Theorem, and whilst I can understand the first part of the proof, I am unsure how the set Sigma's have been worked out.  More importantly, the details of the generating pairs baffles me.  Why can we ignore the central elements in part (a) and then consider only one of them in part (b)?

I have used GAP to verify this computationally for p=7, but it's still not clear to me how this argument has been reached.

I would appreciate some wider thoughts on this please.

[image: Theorem]

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text. They're not user-friendly.

Comment: They are a clipped version from the research paper I am disucussing.  So I am not entirely sure what your issue is here!

Comment: There is a number of limitations coming from the use of pictures - no full text search, inconvenient to view on mobile devices with a narrow screen, inability to copy and paste to use as part of the answer, etc. Also, if you reproduce a part of another paper (whenever yours or someone else's) it is a good practice to give credit to authors and provide a reference.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had sourced the authors.  The paper is by Carta and Fairbairn.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03899